# Rotate Image with Animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

I want to rotate the image 90 degree. everything works fine. but the animation is not working smooth?

**Rotate Code**

```
- (void)rotatePhoto {
    UIImage *rotatedImage;

    if (finalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
        rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: finalImage.CGImage
                                              scale: 1.0
                                        orientation: UIImageOrientationDown];
    else if (finalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown)
        rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: finalImage.CGImage
                                              scale: 1.0
                                        orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
    else if (finalImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft)
        rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: finalImage.CGImage
                                              scale: 1.0
                                        orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
    else
        rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: finalImage.CGImage
                                                     scale: 1.0
                                               orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];

  [self updateImageViewAnimated:rotatedImage]
}
```

I have tried something like that but its not smooth. its rotating but i cant understand

```
 - (void) updateImageViewAnimated:(UIImage *)image
{

    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI /2];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.7;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    [_finalImageView.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

    [UIView transitionWithView:_finalImageView
                      duration:0.7                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^{
                        _finalImageView.image = image;
                    } completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding `UIImageOrientationRight` and so on. These are *inherent* qualities of a photo (e.g. because the photo was taken with the camera rotated). They have nothing to do with rotating an image. To rotate an image with animation, just rotate the image view — that is, apply a rotation transform. Do not use `transitionWithView:`; just rotate (`animateWithDuration:...`). The transform will tell you what the current rotation is and then you can rotate further later as desired.

Comment: But if apply only rotation transform then i will rotate imageview. but i also want to  get the rotated imagenad save this rotated image to document directory...... With rotation transform i will get the rotated image with 90 degree?

Comment: No, rotating the image view does not change the underlying image. But then you can have _separate_ code that derives the rotated version of the underlying image so that you can save it.

Comment: Ok then i will first apply rotation transform of view with animation and after the animation stop i will set the rotated image to the imageview. am i right?

Comment: You could do that (in the completion handler). Or you could just _not_ do it: you could _show_ the user the original image rotated through animation and _save_ the _really_ rotated image.